# How to make a script that automatically types words in a browser/word

Tags: javascript, python

I am NOT asking for a full code, merely how to start. I have a interesting project where I can convert my guitar signal into digital signal, i can link this to a JS file for example.

I hope to do something along the lines of: i play an E-note and the scripts literally writes an E to whatever is open on my pc, so if a word doc is open, the letter E will appear. It should basically function as a virtual keyboard or something. I have the whole input side working, i just need a bit of code that says If .... then 'E' is automatically being written down for example.

Preferably in JS or Python, but anything that you guys could give me as a tip would be more then welcome! I truly dont knwo any sintax that would be able to literally type a letter or a word or something automatically.

Sorry for the weird question and poor explanation! thanks in advance! :D

EDIT

I found that using Pyautogui will be my best bet, honestly it does exactly what I want, the problem is that it seems I was wrong, I can't use Python for this project, only JS........ the bit that would work for me is this line:

pyautogui.press(['left']) # Presses the left arrow key 1 time

If i could place this is a if/else statement it should work, does anyone knows similar method for JS?

Sorry and thanks in advance!

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: Perhaps start here https://towardsdatascience.com/i-built-a-music-sheet-transcriber-heres-how-74708fe7c04c

Answer (score 2):

not quite sure how to convert a guitar note into a letter/word, but you can use pyautogui to automatically type in letters/ words.

```
import pyautogui

if (characterplayedbyguitar) == 'a':
    pyautogui.typewrite("a")
```

and so on and so forth. pyautogui will write in any application that is open when run so it maybe would be wise to add a sleep timer at the beginning of your code.

```
import time

time.sleep (5)
```

I am also quite new to all this and don't fully grasp what you want exactly but I hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for the feedback! I'll try it later tonight! the main problem for me is literally like something happens which triggers something to be written. The idea is that it should write the letter/word to whatever is open at the moment, so a browser or word doc for example.

Comment: Do you know a Javscript alternative?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're wanting to do is process the output of your guitar through some application, such that your operating system emulates keyboard input.

[Pyautogui](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) is a great suggestion:

> PyAutoGUI lets your Python scripts control the mouse and keyboard to automate interactions with other applications. The API is designed to be as simple. PyAutoGUI works on Windows, macOS, and Linux, and runs on Python 2 and 3.

If you just want to do this in a web browser, you might try [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/). You could set it up so that each time you ran the program, the correct website would open. The nice thing about this approach is that you could design your own website to accept the input and do interesting things with it. Combining this with `Pyautogui` creates some interesting possibilities.

> Selenium automates browsers. That's it! What you do with that power is entirely up to you. Primarily it is for automating web applications for testing purposes, but is certainly not limited to just that. Boring web-based administration tasks can (and should) also be automated as well.

For windows, [autohotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) might be helpful, though you'd have to figure out how to get AHK to "read" whatever your guitar's output is and I'm assuming you have `python` installed, so this probably isn't your best bet.

> AutoHotkey gives you the freedom to automate any desktop task. It's small, fast and runs out-of-the-box. Best of all, it's free, open-source (GNU GPLv2), and beginner-friendly. Why not give it a try?

Comment: thanks for the feedback! I'll try it later tonight! the main problem for me is literally like something happens which triggers something to be written. The idea is that it should write the letter/word to whatever is open at the moment, so a browser or word doc for example.

Comment: My best bet is Pyautogui because of:  

pyautogui.press(['left'']) # Press the left arrow key 1 time.

I only hope to find something similar for JS!

Comment: Do you know a Javascript alternative to Pyautogui?